# xcode: Where is dummyViewController instantiated in the default "View-based Application" template?

Tags: xcode, ios, viewcontroller

If I create a New Project in xcode, then choose "View-based Application", the delegate and view controller class templates are generated automatically. Here's a snippet from DummyAppDelegate.h

```
@class dummyViewController;

@interface dummyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    dummyViewController *viewController;
}
```

My main question is: where is instance variable viewController instantiated? I can see no code for this in the generated files, so is some connection in InterfaceBuilder instantiating it automatically?

A second, lesser question is why @class is used in the code above rather than a simple

```
#include "dummyViewController.h"
```

Any help is much appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window, the view controller, and also the application delegate are all loaded from `MainWindow.xib`. Any object you place in a NIB file gets instantiated once that NIB file is loaded. And by specifying MainWindow.nib in the app's Info.plist, you tell Cocoa (actually, the `UIApplication` instance) to automatically load that file on app startup.

The `@class ...` statement is a so-called forward declaration. It is considered good programming practice because its use can shorten compile times (the fewer header files you need import, the faster the compile step is).